# How to access spinner object which i have declared in MainActivity.java into other java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-spinner

I am trying to do some operations on the spinner values in my other class ***extract.java***
but, i am not aware on how to access spinners from ***MainActivity.java***

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         Spinner spin1 = findViewById(R.id.spin1);
         Spinner spin2 = findViewById(R.id.spin2);
         Spinner spin3 = findViewById(R.id.spin3);
```

My other java class ***extract.java***

Are there any import statements to do this?

Comment: When you create your extract.java class you can pass your `Spinner` in constructer, and use it like you want it

Comment: This does not make sense. `Spinner` is a view. You cannot retrieve your values from the `Spinner` object. Why don't you access the values you are setting in the `Spinner` objects in `extract.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public class Extract {
    // class constructor
    public Extract(Spinner spin1, Spinner spin2, Spinner spin3) {
        //do something with your spinners or save them for later use
    }
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
Spinner spin1 = findViewById(R.id.spin1);
Spinner spin2 = findViewById(R.id.spin2);
Spinner spin3 = findViewById(R.id.spin3);
Extract e = new Extract(spin1, spin2, spin3)
```